# How to read a parameter passed by maven on my stylesheet XSL?

Tags: maven, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm running this command:

mvn org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:transform "-DAPP=testingapp"

And inside my XSL I'm transforming a graphml to a HTML and I want to display this app name on the top of my HTML.
How do I read this attribute that I'm passing on the command line on my xsl?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible.

In your **pom.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <transformationSets>
      <transformationSet>
         <parameters>
            <parameter>
               <name>APP</name>
               <value>${APP}</value>
            </parameter>
         </parameters>
      </transformationSet>
   </transformationSets>
</configuration>
```

In your **xsl file**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:param name="APP" />

   <xsl:value-of select="$APP"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will need to declare in **pom.xml** and repeat in your **xsl file**. This is the trick.

Note: This also work for xslt-2.0